# Add lines on the top of a set of files

Tags: bash, perl

I am absolutely not a programmer and have no knowledge in this field.

I always have to add seven lines to the top of my files in order to run them and it's boring.

Is it possible to create a Perl script which would copy the same six lines from a file to a set of files which have the same name except for the number.

#### My seed file would be like this

```
nproc=8
mem=48gb
B3LYP/6-31g(d,p) opt

input

1 1
```

And the names of the files are `test1.com`, `test2.com`, etc.

Their form is like this

```
H 2.3
C 4.1
'blank line'
```

I would like to transform them into

```
nproc=8
mem=48gb
B3LYP/6-31g(d,p) opt

input

1 1
H 2.3
C 4.1
'blank line'
```

I tried modifying a script that I found, but it copied the seven lines at the bottom.

Here is the script I used and which doesn't work (the file is a .sh):

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in `seq 1 1 2` ; do

echo "test"$i.com

head -7 seed.com | tail -7 >> test$i.com

done
```

Comment: Okay, so do your files actually contain `'blank line'`, or is ther just a blank line there? Is ther an empty line before the end of the file? What about the lines that appear blank in your post; are they in the file or just part of your layout?

Comment: The problem I have here is that the task is trivial. It is as if a toddler asked "Please mummy will you colour my pictures for me?" or perhaps it's like asking to copy someone else's homework. Either way, you're abusing the fact that software solutions may be communicated digitally, which is unique amongst the engineering professions. You would *never* ask an automotive engineer, a bricklayer, a rocket scientist, or even your PC maintenance engineer a similar question! I think you should invest a few days of your time in learning to use a tool that is likely to be very useful to you.

Comment: Thank you for the clash, but as a student, I have other worries than learning to code at the moment. I have results to give and I am not a computer guy. But ok, thank you for the remark.

And yes, it's a blank line, empty if you want. And yes, the lines that are blank in the script that I posted have to be blank.

Thank for your answer.

Comment: @Borodin: I don't think the task is trivial: _appending_ to a file is trivial (`>>`), _prepending_ is not, especially if it is to be side-effect free and fast (not an issue here).
Aside from incidentals (`'blank line'`), the question is well-defined, and even contains a solution attempt (however far from an effective solution it may be).
Before it was closed, effective solutions were offered, and there'd be room for more.
While there's certainly room for improvement, I don't think this question should have been closed, nor do I think it deserves the down-votes it got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't actually insert into a file. You can only write over a file. Inserting into a file would look something like the following before being optimized:

1. Set buf_size = num_bytes_to_insert.
2. Open file for rw.
3. Set pos = file_size.
4. While pos > 0,

   1. Set dest_pos = pos.
   2. Set pos = pos - buf_size.
   3. Set pos = 0 if pos < 0.
   4. Seek to position pos.
   5. Set num_bytes_to_read = dest_pos - pos.
   6. Read num_bytes_to_read bytes.
   7. Seek to position pos + num_bytes_to_insert.
   8. Write the bytes read.
5. Seek to position 0.
6. Write the data to be inserted.

Advantages:

- File permissions are preserved.
- Fixed memory overhead (O(1) memory usage).

Disadvantages:

- Complex
- Errors result in loss of data.

---

There are two simpler approaches, one involving reading the entire file into memory, and one involving a temporary file. The following is the latter:

```
cat seed.com "test$i.com" >"test$i.com.tmp" && mv "test$i.com.tmp" "test$i.com"
```

Advantages:

- Simple
- Errors don't result in loss of data.

Disadvantages:

- File permissions are lost.
- Memory overhead proportional to the size of the file (O(N) memory usage).

Comment: Thank you, it's working perfectly.

Comment: It's done. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line

```
head -7 seed.com | tail -7 >> test$i.com
```

I would do it like this

```
( head -n 7 seed.com ; cat test$i.com ) > full_test$i.com
```

That will leave the `test*.com` files as they are, and create new files named `full_test*.com` that will be the combined versions.

You could update the `test*.com` files directly, but if you accidentally ran the script twice then each `test*.com` would then have two headers.

Comment: That'll work, but note that `head` isn't needed at all, given that the entire `seed.com` file should be prepended. Also, while a subshell does no harm here, a group command (`{ ...;  ...; }`) is sufficient; that said, if both files are `cat`ted, a simple command will do: `cat seed.com "test$i.com"`, as in ikegami's answer.

Comment: Thank you, I used Ikegami's solution and it worked. Thank you.